# How to make EXCEPT clause case insensitive in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

On a single column of two different tables, I want to use the [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause like:

```
Select Col1 From TABLE_1
Except
Select Col1 From TABLE_2
```

Is there any expression to be added to this query so that it becomes **case-insensitive** i.e. a value like `ABCD` in *Col1* of *TABLE_1* is interpreted to be the same as `AbCd` in *Col1* of *TABLE_2*, and `ABCD` does not appear in the result of the above query.

Comment: SQL Server uses case-insensitive collation by default - what collation are you using in those tables and/or columns right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use case-insensitive `COLLATION`:

```
Select Col1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS From TABLE_1
Except
Select Col1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS From TABLE_2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the collation is different on both columns.
Use you can use the COLLATE clause in the statement like so

```
Select Col1 COLLATE <name_of_Collation_of_Column> From TABLE_1
Except
Select Col1  COLLATE <name_of_Collation_of_Column> From TABLE_2
```